# What auxiliary verb should be used with a country name?

Tags: nouns, pronouns, articles

Could anyone tell which statement is correct :
1. India is playing
2. India are playing

Comment: What makes you think one of those is wrong?

Comment: @tchrist If none of them is incorrect then what is the difference?

Comment: See the linked duplicate. Also, use *neither* not *none* when you have only two items, just like you should use *both* not *all*.

Comment: I suppose a sportswriter with dual UK - US citizenship might decide to change from 'India is playing' to 'India are playing' halfway across the Atlantic (eastbound).